# É aconselhável escrever testes automatizados para a interface com o usuário?

Tags: testes-de-unidade, tdd, gui

Quando se trata de testes unitários e TDD, normalmente pensamos nos testes da chamada "lógica do negócio", que são baseadas nos requisitos, etc.

Mas encontramos na web também exemplos de testes da interface com o usuário, principalmente na web, mas também no desktop às vezes.

Exemplos:

- [Nesta página do Google Testing Blog](http://googletesting.blogspot.com.br/2014/07/testing-on-toilet-dont-put-logic-in.html), são testadas ações do usuário no Google+:

```java
@Test public void shouldNavigateToPhotosPage() {
  String baseUrl = "http://plus.google.com/";
  Navigator nav = new Navigator(baseUrl);
  nav.goToPhotosPage();
  assertEquals(baseUrl + "/u/0/photos", nav.getCurrentUrl());
}
```

- Nas página do [site do QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) há exemplos de testes de manipulação de DOM (se um elemento se tornou visível depois de uma ação do usuário, etc.)

Acontece que testar a interface parece ser bem trabalhoso, realmente não sei se vale a pena.

É recomendado criar testes automatizados para a interface, ou isto devemos testar "na mão" mesmo?

Comment: Vou tentar postar uma resposta melhor, veja por exemplo o [ZombieJs](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) e o [cucumberJs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js), juntos permitem criar uma boa cobertura de testes usando BDD é uma idéia de ter testes com interface e com não tanto esforço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A maior parte dos seus testes automatizados deve* ser sobre a sua regra de negócio (testes unitários).
- Uma parte menor deve testar a integração destas regras de negócio entre si e com outras camadas do sistema (testes de serviço).
- Uma pequena parte deve testar sua interface com o usuário onde ela for mais crítica para o negócio (UI).

*"Deve": todos os "deve" aqui são relativos pois isso vai depender de inúmeras variáveis no seu ambiente. Mas enquanto você ainda não souber por experiência própria exatamente o que fazer, siga as instruções genéricas de quem já vivenciou muito isso e está disposto a ajudar.

Recomendo ler este artigo: [Martin Fowler - TestPyramid](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html).

Comment: Bom artigo. Nunca tinha ouvido falar em *Test Pyramid* antes.